Connecting GridDB instance using the StoreFactory.get_store() method
I'm trying to connect to my GridDB instance using the StoreFactory.get_store() method, but I keep encountering the following error:
TypeError: StoreFactory.get_store() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cluster_name'
here is the code  am using:
import griddb_python as griddb

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

 #Trying to connect to the GridDB cluster
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host="127.0.0.1", 
    port=390001, 
    Cluster_name="myCluster", 
    username="admin", 
    password="password"
)

I followed the official GridDB documentation, but the error persists. Have the function parameters changed in the recent version of the GridDB Python client? Or am I missing something in the configuration?
